# how to use ionic.Platform

Tags: ionic-framework, device-detection

I'm very new to using ionic/AngularJS and I was wondering how exactly to use ionic.Platform to print the current device. Right now I have

```
var currentPlatform = ionic.Platform.platform();
```

in my main.html ctrl. Is there a way to send it to the html page, or am I approaching it completely wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

from your controller data send to view use **application model $scope** , means just assign your variable to scope variable and get it directly where you call your controller in view.

**Example :**

```
    angular.module('scopeExample', ['ionic'])
    .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
          var currentPlatform = ionic.Platform.platform();  
          $scope.currentPlatform = currentPlatform;
    }]);
```

and in **view** you access

```
      <body ng-app="scopeExample">
        <ion-pane>
          <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
            <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
          </ion-header-bar>
          <ion-content ng-controller="MyController">
           {{currentPlatform }}
          </ion-content>
        </ion-pane>
      </body>
```

For more details refer following links :

[link1](http://santoshshinde2012.blogspot.in/2015/03/hybrid-mobile-apps-with-ionic-framework.html),[link2](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) & [link3](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/) etc.

Hopes this will help you.